# How to pass a drawer with a string inside to next screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the next block of code where I'm getting the AppVersion using a library and after that I'm passing the AppVersion to a drawer. That drawer I send it to next screen but when I open the drawer on the next screen is showing the AppVersion as NULL. What can be the issue ?
I will provide below the full code source and maybe somebody can help me to figure out where is the bug.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:package_info/package_info.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(FirstPage());
}
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  FirstPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  String packageAppVersion = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    versionCheck();
  }

  Future<void> versionCheck() async {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    setState(() {
      packageAppVersion = packageInfo.version;
    });
  }

  Widget buildDrawerForSecondPage(BuildContext context) {
    return new Drawer(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: new ListView(
                children: <Widget>[],
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 0,
              child: Text("App version: $packageAppVersion"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Drawer Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SecondPage(
        title: 'Second Page',
        drawer: buildDrawerForSecondPage(context),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final Drawer drawer;

  SecondPage({Key key, this.title, this.drawer}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState(drawer);
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  String packageAppVersion = '';
  final Drawer drawer;

  _SecondPageState(this.drawer);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      endDrawer: drawer,
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using a `.then()` syntax, the `AppVersion` actually gets updated but a bit later hence the `null` value. You could `await` the version before the `run()` method and then pass it down to `MaterialApp`, or you could try using a `setState` after the print inside `then()`. Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, the value of `packageAppVersion` is null, that is what it is being shown in the UI. So to update the UI you need to use `setState`. Check the below code for a better understanding:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  versionCheck();
}

Future<void> versionCheck() async {
  PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
  setState((){
    packageAppVersion = packageInfo.version;
  });
  print('App version received: $packageAppVersion');
}
```

Comment: I don't show the AppVersion on the first screen. I display it on the second screen ( LoginPage).

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix for above code, but I don't understand why is working only like this (removed the `drawer` property and the constructor from the `_SecondPageState`) :

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final Drawer drawer;

  SecondPage({Key key, this.title, this.drawer}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  String packageAppVersion = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      endDrawer: widget.drawer,
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```